# Android N Emulator Image with Google Play Services

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-7.0-nougat

I try to set up the Android Studio emulator for the Developer Preview of the newest Android N (API 24). As I set up the emulator with Android N and started the my app, it suggested me to update the Google Play Services. I clicked on "UPDATE" and nothing happened. As I clicked through the app, it crashes.

I tried several things. I tried Genymotion, but I couldn't find a image for API 24. As well, I couldn't find any image of Android N with Google Play Services for Virtualbox.

Is there a way to set up the API 24 image for the emulator?

Comment: Which Android Studio version are you using?

Comment: My Android Studio version is 2.1.2

Comment: Appears the latest updates to the emulator include a proper version of Google Play Services. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38415895/how-to-create-avd-with-android-7-0-with-google-apis