# How to create AVD with Android & (7.0) with Google APIs?

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services, android-virtual-device, android-7.0-nougat

When I downloaded and select "N" (API = 24) for the AVD, I see the following message on bottom right:

> Consider using a System Image with Google APIs to enable testing with Google Play Services.

Is this image not available yet? or am I missing something? I dont see it in  the SDK Manager yet.

[image]

Comment: Late August and this is still an issue. Yay Google.

Comment: Yes, the issue continue... anyone have found a solution?? I tried using Android Studion 2.2 Beta but the problem exists too.

Answer (score 3):

As of SDK Tools 25.1.7 and Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image Rev. 6, it appears that there is no longer a separate emulator image for the Google APIs - instead, the normal emulator image now includes the Google APIs by default.  So, the message shown in the "Recommendation" section when creating an AVD appears to be old/incorrect.

I was able to run [this project](https://github.com/OneBusAway/onebusaway-android) (using `gradlew installObaGoogleDebug`), which requires Google Play Services for maps and other items, by selecting Nougat / API Level 24 / x86_64 / Android 7.0.

[image]

**EDIT Nov. 3rd 2016**

It appears this was a temporary issue with the emulator image.  As of SDK Tools 25.2.2 and Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image Rev. 7, when I try to run the same app on the same emulator image (API Level 24) I created above, it now says "OneBusAway relies on Google Play Services, which is not supported on your device".

However, it looks like there is now an API Level 25 (Android 7.1.1) emulator w/ ABI x86_64 available for download that does explictly include the Google APIs - see area circled in red below (note that the update message still seems to erronouesly appear):

[image]

Comment: Verified this now works. Update since August 23rd must have fixed something as the same emulator failed on the 23rd, but works now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, I think it's probably a bug with the tool.

I was able to solve it by downloading the `x86_64` version, and then it allowed me to use both the `N x86` and `N x86_64` emulator images.